# Unable to use WebIDE to interact with KaiOS emulator

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, firefox-os, web-ide

I followed the official guide given [here](https://developer.kaiostech.com/simulator). Got so far as `./b2g-bin -profile ./gaia/profile -start-debugger-server 6000`. The simulator window launched up, displayed the KaiOS logo but would go no further. 
Then, I tried using `sudo`. That seemed to have worked, as now the simulator went all the way to display the clock.

Launched WebIDE from Firefox and added a Remote Runtime. Then created a HelloWorld app, but the button to 'Install and Run' is disabled.

Where did I go wrong?

Here is the terminal output, if that is any help:

```
(b2g:3992): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained.css:27:19: Missing name of pseudo-class

(b2g:3992): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained.css:2780:55: Not a valid image
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm, line 410: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]
1532463036227   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 2828
--*-- KillSwitchMain: No proper libcutils binding, aborting.
PermissionsTable.jsm: expandPermissions: Invalid access for permission storage: readwrite
PermissionsTable.jsm: expandPermissions: Unknown Permission: device-storage:audiosPermissionsTable.jsm: expandPermissions: Invalid access for permission storage: readwrite
PermissionsInstaller.jsm: 'device-storage:audios' is not a valid Webapps permission name.###################################### forms.js loaded
###################################### BrowserElementCopyPaste.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanningAPZDisabled.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanning.js loaded
######################## BrowserElementChildPreload.js loaded
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://calculator.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
[]
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://todo.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
[]
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://contact.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
[]
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://geoloc.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
[]
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-requestconfirmation"
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-requestpasskey"
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-requestpincode"
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-authorize"
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-cancel"
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-pairedstatuschanged"
Could not register invalid system message entry for app://engmode.gaiamobile.org/manifest.webapp
"bluetooth-hfp-status-changed"
Opening debugger server on 6000
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/navigation_map.js, line 49: ReferenceError: NT_DOM_HELPER is not defined
XXX FIXME : Dispatch a mozChromeEvent: system-first-paint
XXX FIXME : Dispatch a mozChromeEvent: webapps-registry-ready
JavaScript error: jar:file:///home/rijumone/Downloads/b2g/omni.ja!/components/nsDOMIdentity.js, line 8: Error: navigator.id.watch was already called
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/antitheft_manager.js, line 1: NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED: 
###################################### BrowserElementCopyPaste.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanningAPZDisabled.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanning.js loaded
######################## BrowserElementChildPreload.js loaded
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/PhoneNumberUtils.jsm, line 2: NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND: Component returned failure code: 0x80520012 (NS_ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND) [nsIXPCComponents_Utils.import]
JavaScript error: app://launcher.gaiamobile.org/dist/app.bundle.js, line 3: TypeError: navigator.mozMobileConnections is undefined
XXX FIXME : Got a mozContentEvent: system-message-listener-ready
1532463038128   AlarmsService   DEBUG   init()
1532463038129   AlarmsService   DEBUG   _restoreAlarmsFromDb()
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/software_button_manager.js, line 5: TypeError: this._currentOrientation.index is not a function
1532463038201   AlarmsService   DEBUG   Callback after getting alarms from database: []
1532463038201   AlarmsService   DEBUG   Current alarm: null
1532463038201   AlarmsService   DEBUG   Alarm queue: []
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/dist/bundle.js, line 1: TypeError: e is undefined
###################################### BrowserElementCopyPaste.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanningAPZDisabled.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanning.js loaded
######################## BrowserElementChildPreload.js loaded
JavaScript error: resource://gre/modules/DOMIdentity.jsm, line 19: Error: PERMISSION_DENIED
Could not have FTU: manifestURL:undefined, _ftu:null
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/statusbar.js, line 74: ReferenceError: Bluetooth is not defined
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/app_transition_controller.js, line 19: TypeError: Service.query(...) is null
JavaScript error: jar:file:///home/rijumone/Downloads/b2g/omni.ja!/components/BrowserElementParent.js, line 98: NS_ERROR_NOT_IMPLEMENTED: SetNFCFocus for in-process mode is not yet supported
XXX FIXME : Got a mozContentEvent: inputmethod-update-layouts
XXX FIXME : Got a mozContentEvent: inputmethod-update-layouts
JavaScript error: app://launcher.gaiamobile.org/dist/app.bundle.js, line 4: TypeError: navigator.mozVoicemail is undefined
JavaScript error: app://system.gaiamobile.org/js/statusbar.js, line 51: TypeError: this.icons.dataConnection is undefined
###################################### BrowserElementCopyPaste.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanningAPZDisabled.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanning.js loaded
######################## BrowserElementChildPreload.js loaded
Keyboard.jsm Warning: There are more than one content page with input-manage permission. There will be undeterministic responses to addInput()/removeInput() if both content pages are trying to respond to the same request event.

(/home/rijumone/Downloads/b2g/plugin-container:4087): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained.css:27:19: Missing name of pseudo-class

(/home/rijumone/Downloads/b2g/plugin-container:4087): Gtk-WARNING **: Theme parsing error: gtk-contained.css:2780:55: Not a valid image
###################################### forms.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanningAPZDisabled.js loaded
############################### browserElementPanning.js loaded
###################################### BrowserElementCopyPaste.js loaded
######################## BrowserElementChildPreload.js loaded
JavaScript error: app://launcher.gaiamobile.org/dist/app.bundle.js, line 3: TypeError: navigator.mozBluetooth is undefined
 -*- Shell.js: Starting USB debugger on 6000
XXX FIXME : Dispatch a mozPrefChromeEvent: undefined
XXX FIXME : Dispatch a mozChromeEvent: remote-debugger-prompt
XXX FIXME : Got a mozContentEvent: remote-debugger-prompt
*** UTM:SVC TimerManager:notify - notified @mozilla.org/b2g/webapps-update-timer;1
```

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: @sv94, nope. You got anything?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the connection between WebIDE and emulator is established?
Usually it takes some time to initialize the emulator.

```
...
######################## BrowserElementChildPreload.js loaded
JavaScript error: app://launcher.gaiamobile.org/dist/app.bundle.js, line 3: TypeError: 
navigator.mozBluetooth is undefined
 -*- Shell.js: Starting USB debugger on 6000                           <<<<<<<< NOW TRY TO CONNECT
XXX FIXME : Dispatch a mozPrefChromeEvent: undefined
XXX FIXME : Dispatch a mozChromeEvent: remote-debugger-prompt
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to Firefox 43 and try to install the Firefox simulator in that version. It works for me:)

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade to Firefox v59. You can download it from from [here](https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/nightly/2017/11/2017-11-19-22-01-26-mozilla-central/). I have tried this and can confirm that it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to launch in windows OS it is almost impossible but if you have ubuntu OS in real or in oracle VM for windows then the simulator Remote runtime is not working since the runtime is in local,no need of remote connection, this item  will be removed afterward,you just only need to launch/run the kaiosrt file after exracting zip file you download in ubuntu OS from here- https://developer.kaiostech.com/simulator/linux

Also please read instruction before trying KaiOS simulator- https://s3.amazonaws.com/kaicloudsimulatordl/release_note.pdf